# Why does du report a different file size from ls on this single file?

Tags: unix

Hello I am trying to find size of a huge directory in my Unix system.

I'm using the command "du -k". But it is giving me weird results.

I narrowed down to just check the size of one tif file.

When did a **ls -l**

```
-rw-rw-rw-   1 dsp.ts5  datafeed 83239394 Jun 10  2013 V001.tif
```

The file size here is approx 83MB.

and when executed **du -k V001.tif**

```
108914  V001.tif
```

The file size here is 108MB!

I am having a hard time finding out why the two commands are returning different results?

Comment: What do you mean by "size"? `ls -ld /p/a/t/h` will tell you the size of the directory, but not the number of links in it nor the total amount of disk consumed by the files which have links in the directory.

Comment: the `-s` in du means summary. What do you get if you just run `du -k V001.tif`? (Please edit your question to show this info). Good luck.

Comment: What unix variant is it? What's the filesystem type? If you make a copy of that file, what do `du -k` and `ls -l` report about that file?

Comment: Some UNIXs alow files to have 'gaps' i.e. not physically occupy disk space but are reserved.

Comment: @Gilles... I'm having Solaris as an OS, not sure about file system, dropped a note to the admin though. What exactly you imply from copying file? Making a duplicate and checking the size?

Comment: @EdHeal.. hmm... but a difference of almost 25MB for a file of size 80MB is just too much. Considering for files over 24TB, this gap is just driving me nuts. Anyway I can get actual size of files without the gaps you mentioned?

Comment: What file system is this? I have seen similar on XFS file systems. Under certain circumstances, XFS will pre-allocate additional space in case the file gets expanded. It will eventually de-allocate the extra if it's never used, but can lead to confusing calculations in the meantime. It wouldn't surprise me to find VxFS or ZFS or others doing something similar...

Comment: wow.. never thought about that. Thanks for pushing this towards a good direction. So, how did you manage to get the actual file size 
in case of XFS/VxFs or anyother?

Comment: @webExplorer Use `stat()` or the command-line equivalent `stat` (although that's on Linux - not sure if Solaris provides a `stat` command line). If that's not available, parse the output of `ls`, which is generally disrecommended, but if you have no other alternatives...

Comment: Sparse file ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Comment: @igr Sparse files typically use less space than what their file size would indicate, not more. I suspect this is some kind of pre-allocation or reserved space...

Comment: @twalberg you are right, I 'scanned' too fast.

Answer (score 0):

`du -k` returns the number of 1K blocks.

`ls -l` shows the number of bytes.

It's important to understand the flags that you pass to your programs.  I think you're using `du -sk` without understanding why you need the `-s` or the `-k`.  Specifically, `-s` makes no sense if you are giving it the name of a single file, because `-s` is for summarizing the results of many files or directories.

`man du` and `man ls` will tell you all about the options that you can use.

Comment: Your factual statements are correct, but they don't do anything to explain the inconsistency.

Comment: Thank you Andy, I checked the options, and tried getting the filesize using `du -k`. Confusingly, still the size doesnt match up with `ls -l`